Kernel of the thin-plate-energy
Consider the following cost function
$$
E[f] = \int_{\mathbb{R^N}} \sum_{|\alpha| = 2} \binom{2}{\alpha} |D^{\alpha}f|^2 dx_1 \dots dx_n
$$
here $\alpha$ is a multi-index and $D^{\alpha}f$ denotes the derivatives with give multi-indices
I am trying to find $f$ such that $E[f]=0$, since the integrand is sum of positive contribution then $E[f] = 0$ iff
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2} = 0 & i =1,\dots,n \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} = 0 & i = 1,\dots,n, \;\; j = i+1, \dots n
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I am a bit confused on how to solve this system, but I know the final result should be
$$
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = b + a_1x_1 + \dots + a_n x_n
$$
Maybe is very trivial but I get confused on how to carry with the calculations.
Can you help?

Have you tried the calculation with $n = 2, 3, \dots$ to see what happens? If so, try to generalise the calculation or use induction. Also, the indexing for the cross derivative term seems to imply that this condition only holds when $i < j$ but this would be inconsistent with Clairauts theorem so it must hold for all $j \ne i$

I tried to start with non mixed derivatives and for each one I obtain $f = a_i x_i + b_i$ where the coefficients don't depends on the i-th variabile. But I don't know how to use the mixed derivatives and how to reach the conclusion

Try $n=2$. Note that $f\in C^{2} \implies f_{x_{1}x_{2}}=f_{x_{2}x_{1}}$ so $$f_{x_{1} x_{2}}=0 \implies f=a_{1}(x_{1})+a_{2}(x_{2}) \tag 1$$ Further \begin{align}
f_{x_{1}x_{1}}=0\implies f&=c_{1}+b_{1}x_{1}+\hat{b}{1}(x{2}) \tag 2 \
f_{x_{2}x_{2}}=0\implies f&=c_{2}+b_{2}x_{2}+\hat{b}{2}(x{1}) \tag 3
\end{align} Equating \begin{align}
a_{1}(x_{1})&=c_{1}+b_{1}x_{1}=\hat{b}{2}(x{1}) \
a_{2}(x_{1})&=c_{2}+b_{2}x_{2}=\hat{b}{1}(x{2}) \
\end{align} so from $(1)$ \begin{align}
f&=c_{1}+b_{1}x_{1}+c_{2}+b_{2}x_{2} \
&=c+b_{1}x_{1}+b_{2}x_{2}
\end{align} Now try to generalise.

Maybe this is silly, how do you know $(1)$ is yrue

You integrate sequentially
\begin{align}
f_{x_{1} x_{2}} = 0 \implies f_{x_{1}} &= a(x_{1}) \
\implies f &= \int a(x_{1}) dx_{1} \
&= a_{1}(x_{1}) + a_{2}(x_{2})
\end{align}

And for $(2)$ and $(3)$ where do $c_1, c_2$ come from? Wouldn't it just be $f = b_1(x_2) x_1 + b_2(x_2)$ for $(2)$ for example?

The form of $f$ in $(1)$ precludes solutions of the form $f = x_{1} b_{1}(x_{2}) + b_{2}(x_{2}) = B_{1}(x_{1}, x_{2}) + b_{2}(x_{2})$, while the $c_{i}$ can be absorbed into the $\hat{b}_{i}$ but I prefer to make things explicit.

You can always start with $(2)$ and $(3)$ instead to get \begin{align} f_{x_{1} x_{1}} = 0 \implies f &= c_{1} + x_{1} b_{1}(x_{2}) + \hat{b}{1}(x{2}) \  f_{x_{2} x_{2}} = 0 \implies f &= c_{2} + x_{2} b_{2}(x_{1}) + \hat{b}{2}(x{1}) \end{align} then differentiate \begin{align} f_{x_{1} x_{2}} &= b_{1}(x_{2}) ' = 0 \implies b_{1}(x_{2}) = b_{1} = \text{constant} \ f_{x_{2} x_{1}} &= b_{2}(x_{1})' = 0 \implies b_{2}(x_{1}) = b_{2} = \text{constant} \end{align}

Just out of curiosity, why doesn't such term pop out from the Euler Lagrange equations? (I think I understood anyway I'll post an answer soon).
